# Developing an Algorithm for Tree Mutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation, pseudocode

I have to come up with an efficient algorithm that takes a tree in this format:

```
    ?           
   /  \       
  ?    ?      
 / \  / \  
G  A  A  A
```

and fills in the question mark nodes with the values that provide the least amount of mutations.  The values can only be {A, C, T, G}.  The tree will always have this same shape and amount of nodes.  Also, it will always have the leaf nodes filled in and the remaining nodes will be question marks that need to be filled.

For instance, the tree on the right is correct and has less mutations than the one on the left.

```
    A           A
   /  \        /  \
  G    G      A    A
 / \  / \    / \  / \
G  A  A  A  G  A  A  A
```

A mutation occurs when a parent node differs from a child node.  So, the above left tree contains five mutations and the above right has one.

Can someone help me out by providing psuedocode?  Thanks.

Comment: How do you define a mutation? I don't have deep knowledge about Biology. (Please edit your question to include this info)

Comment: You need to provide more info.  By your logic, a tree with all A's would have the fewest mutations, but a tree with all A's would not contain any biologically significant data.

Comment: Do all of the input trees have the leaf cells filled in with letters, and question marks in all other nodes?  Are the trees always full binary trees?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like dynamic programming from the bottom of the tree up. For each node you want to work out the least cost solution that leaves that node marked A, C, T, or G, for each of these possibilities. You work this out by using previously calculated costs for each possibility for the nodes immediately below that node. The code just to work out the cost might be a bit like this.

```
LeastCost(node, colourHere)
{
  foreach colour
    leastLeft[colour] = LeastCost(leftChild, colour)
    leastRight[colour] = LeastCost(rightChild, colour)
  best = infinity
  foreach combination
    cost = leastLeft[combination.leftColour] +
      leastRight[combination.rightColour]
    if (combination.leftColour != colourHere)
      cost++;
    if (combination.rightColour != colourHere)
      cost++;
    if (cost < best)
      cost = best;
  return cost
}
```

To return the best answer as well as the best cost you need to keep track of the combination corresponding to the best answer as well. Come to think about it, you can save time by working out the answers for all four colours at each node at the same time.